# Spelling out an acronym if first seen in the table of contents and do you spell it out in the paragraph title as well so that they match?

Tags: acronyms

If a **subject title** is first spelled out in the **table of contents**, do you still spell out that same acronym when you get to the **paragraph** **title** within the document so that it is **matching** the table of contents title?

I ask because I am told that you only spell out the acronym the first time it is seen.

Comment: What sort of publication is this? If it's a internationally published text then it'll matter a lot more (and probably be dealt with in the publisher's style guides) than if it's a high school homework assignment (where no one will notice).

Comment: What is a "subject title"?

Comment: I would assume that it should be spelled out the first time it occurs _in the text_ - tables of contents don't count.

Comment: @KillingTime a strangely depressed view of education? Why do you assume no-one cares about detail in high school? In my experience it is older folk who are more slipshod as they age, because they can’t be bothered, and life  has taught them that they can get away with sloppiness.

Comment: Can you add more detail, please?

Every reference to anything should always match but what do you mean by "spell out the acronym…" whether the first time it is seen or not?

Do you mean to spell out NASA as National Aeronautical and Space Administration, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The guideline at every publisher I've ever worked for is that table of contents (TOC) entries and chapter title/subhead entries should match exactly. Many book TOCs include only chapter titles—not subheads—but others include at least the primary subheads, and sometimes secondary subheads as well.

In any event, the wording of whatever chapter titles and subheads appear in the TOC is supposed to match their wording in the main text. Here is a glancing mention of this rule in *The Chicago Manual of Style*, sixteenth edition (2010) in a discussion of proofreading:

> **2.130 *Double-checking proofs.*** ... Check article or chapter titles and, if necessary, subheads or other heads against the table of contents to ensure consistent wording, and verify or add beginning page numbers in the table of contents.

*The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) offers similar advice:

> **1.2.10 Contents** ... The wording, punctuation, and capitalization of part and chapter titles must be consistent with that used in text, although the designer may subsequently alter the styling, for example using even full capitals or full and small capitals rather than capitals and lower case.

So the answer to your question is yes: if a subject title is first spelled out in the table of contents, you should spell out that same acronym when you get to the paragraph title within the document so that it matches the table of contents title.

In most instances, of course, authors write the chapter titles and subheads first and the TOC much later—near the end of the process, in fact—meaning that, technically, the TOC wording is matching the main text wording, and not vice versa. But either way, the two should match.

Beyond that, publishers vary on the question of whether to permit authors to introduce acronym/initialisms parenthetically in a chapter title or subhead or to do so only in running text. For example, an author might have a chapter title that reads "Recent Developments in Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence." If the author intends to abbreviate "machine learning" as "ML" and "artificial intelligence" as "AI" throughout the discussion in the running text—and if neither term has come up previously in the book or essay—should the abbreviated forms be noted in the chapter title or should that parenthetical explanation be saved for the running text? That is, should the chapter title read saved "Recent Developments in Machine Learning (ML) and Artificial Intelligence (AI)" or simply as "Recent Developments in Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence"?

Some publishers prefer to provide parenthetical abbreviations only in actual running text. For example:

> **Recent Developments in Machine Learning and Artificial Intelligence**
>
> Researchers have made tremendous strides in machine learning (ML) and artificial intelligence (AI) over the past three years. ...

Others prefer to establish the acronyms/initialisms as soon as possible and start using the short forms immediately thereafter. For example:

> **Recent Developments in Machine Learning (ML) and Artificial Intelligence (AI)**
>
> Researchers have made tremendous strides in ML and AI over the past three years. ...

This is a matter of house style preference or of writer preference (if no house style preference exists). But either way, by convention, the wording used in the TOC and the wording used in the chapter title should match.

Comment: Absolutely. All references to anything should always use the same style… else, why trust the writer? What that style should be is a matter of choice to be agreed between author and publisher

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard rule other than taking the trouble to define a term or acronym on first *use*.

Functionally, the first *use* is when the discussion of the concept begins, in the text of an article. If the acronym is used in the paragraph heading, it may be defined there on the assumption that a reader, having read the heading, will read the paragraph. No further definition is needed within the paragraph text.

The table of contents has the function of giving the reader a guide to the contents, allowing them to pick whichever section or paragraph they like. It therefore cannot be assumed that the reader will read the paragraph with the first *use* of the acronym, so it seems sensible and courteous to put the acronym definition in the table of contents. The same argument applies to acronyms in the main title of the article if it uses them.

In this way, the reader is offered definition in the article title (if appropriate), in the table of contents, and in the paragraph heading.

Other acronyms in the text not used in the title or headings should be defined once as usual on first use.

(Practically and conveniently, the use of asterisked acronyms may direct the reader’s attention to the definition in footnotes.)

Comment: Anton, might you be over-stating the case?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin yes I may be a little too prescriptive in my concern to encourage clarity. Examples such as NATO, DIY and RIP come to mind as some that it would be tedious to define too often.

Comment: I apologise. I must have mis-read something because in fact, I entirely agree with you.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Kind of you - Thanks.